# Copy and paste is too slow for copying notes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wanted a macro that could copy powerpoint notes to a text file and I found this [macro](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00481_Export_the_notes_text_of_a_presentation.htm) online. However I found that obviously didn't preserve formatting which I required so I wrote this macro instead.

```
Sub TestNotes()
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc

    Dim objSelection

    Dim oSlides As Slides
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSl In oSlides
        For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
                    objSelection.TypeText ("Slide: " & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf)
                    objSelection.Range.Paste
                    objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Next oSh
    Next oSl

End Sub
```

The problem is that when you run it the copy and paste action is too slow and all the slide notes get mixed up. I tried using `DoEvents`, however, that proved ineffective. Is there a way to achieve what I want using a macro? In other words how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is getting messed up because you are using objSelection.Range.Paste. Just replace this with

objSelection.Paste

This should resolve your issue with text getting messed up.